# Win 10 Libraries option "Arrange by" won't display pictures from previous years?

Tags: windows-10, sorting, date, libraries, pictures

It's simple as the title. On Windows 10, when I go to "Libraries", then to "Pictures" I can see folders that I included in a Library. When I open the folder, all the pictures are there and I can see them, open, "Sort by" etc.

[Everything works when not arranged.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atbt7.png)

But when I go on "Arrange by", e.g. Day or Month, it shows only pictures from this year, down to 9th January. For older folders in which I didn't add any new pictures, it says "This folder is empty."

[When I arrange by month, day, or anything other, it says the folder is empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V414F.png)

As I said, in a folder that I added new pictures this year, it shows only a few photos down to 9th January.
The only possible reason that I found is that folders from drive D:/ are affected. Pictures from "My Pictures" folder on C:/ arranges fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has implemented a poorly-documented *Group by* feature in Explorer, This might be causing the issue.

Try to resolve it  by *right-clicking* in the right Windows Explorer pane. The context menu now includes *Group by*, and defaults to by date. Uncheck that option.

[image: Group by in Explorer]

If that is not the cause, please let me know and I'll remove this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but no, it didn't help. :/